# Can't connect to wifi network for the first time with QnetworkSession Qt

Tags: qt, qml, ubuntu-14.04

i am using [QNetworkSession](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworksession.html) and [QNetworkConfigurationManager](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkconfigurationmanager.html) class for scanning and connecting to Available Wifi networks.

```
SessionWidget::SessionWidget(const QNetworkConfiguration &config, QObject *parent):QObject(parent)
    {

        session = new QNetworkSession(config, this);
        session->open();
        connect(session, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QNetworkSession::State)),
            this, SLOT(updateSessionState(session->state)));
     }


void SessionWidget::updateSessionState(QNetworkSession::State state)
    {

        switch (state) {
        case QNetworkSession::Invalid:
            qDebug("Network Status :: Invalid");
            break;
        case QNetworkSession::NotAvailable:
            qDebug("Network Status ::NotAvailable");
            break;
        case QNetworkSession::Connecting:
            qDebug("Network Status ::Connecting");
            break;
        case QNetworkSession::Connected:
            emit uiSignal("Connected",session->configuration().name());
            qDebug("Network Status ::Connected");
            break;
        case QNetworkSession::Closing:
            qDebug("Network Status :: Closing");
            break;
        case QNetworkSession::Disconnected:
            emit uiSignal("Disconnected",session->configuration().name());
               qDebug("Network Status :: Disconnected");
            break;
        case QNetworkSession::Roaming:
                qDebug("Network Status :: Roming");
            break;    
        default:
            qDebug("Network Status :: Unknown");
            qDebug(" ");
        }
            break;
        case QNetworkSession::Disconnected:
            emit uiSignal("Disconnected",session->configuration().name());
               qDebug("Network Status :: Disconnected");
            break;
        case QNetworkSession::Roaming:
                qDebug("Network Status :: Roming");
            break;    
        default:
            qDebug("Network Status :: Unknown");
            qDebug(" ");
        }
```

I can connect to a network which is connected at least once to the system(through Ubuntu).
if i try to connect to the network for the first time through my application get the  **QNetworkSession::Invalid** flag.I am using Ubuntu 14.04  platform

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your updateSessionState(session->state()) too early.

Qt documentation says clearly that QNetworkSession::open is **asyncronous** therefore if you want to have information about the state of the session you have to wait for the session to tell you that something has changed. 
To obtain this you have to write a slot and to connect it to the stateChanged() signal.
You also have the opened() signal and the error signal() which will respectively trigger when the session connection is open or when you have an error.

Comment: @Macro  i have Updated the question... it is not the problem....the code is working perfectly for networks that are connected at least once to the OS.  i am getting "invalide" flag for a new network which were never ever connected before to OS. thank you so much for your fast responce

Comment: I understand, the best thing to do now is to connect a slot also to the error( QNetworkSession::SessionError error ) SIGNAL. if you get an error this way you will find some more info about what is causing the error. If you do not get any error then I am running out of ideas.

Comment: i did what u have said ... but logging no error...thank you for your support

Comment: It won't work for the reasons I've already given you in the previous question. Addition and deletation of configurations can only be done by the user or via native code. Once the configuration is registered, it is valid and can be used, as you experienced with your code.